# How can I avoid supporting unethical/criminal behavior reagrding fiscal matters when travelling?

Tags: money, payment-cards, taxes, ethical-travel, vat

When travelling, I am often offered to pay in cash, with the risk of the business I am completing the transaction not paying VAT.

On the other hand, if I pay by credit card, there is a non-zero risk that the credit card provider is eluding the corporate tax payment (see [just one example of receiving 3.3 milions tax credit over revenues of around 8'000 milions](https://web.archive.org/web/20190211203722/https://www.smh.com.au/business/the-economy/american-express-pays-no-tax-on-multibilliondollar-australian-operation-for-seven-years-20150611-ghlg6t.html) I found with 2 minutes google research).

How to minimize the impact, disincentiving unethical behavior (i.e. giving the smaller reward to unethical behavior)?

Disclaimer: I consider tax elusion unethical, I equate unethical to criminal.

Disclaimer/background clarification: when paying by credit card, the customer may have no fees, but the business receiving the payment has to give some percent/fixed aumont to the credit card provider. Considering that the business may have a net profit on the price you pay ranging from 5% to 100%, a credit card fee of 1% may be taking away something from 20% to 1% of the net profit of the business. Yes, a business having 100% net profit, i.e. no cost on their services, it is a purely imaginary business.

Comment: Downvoters: please leave a feedback to help me improve the question

Comment: Upvoter here: using "criminal" in title may seems to strong, and in most jurisdiction it is not a crime (just an offence)

Comment: The premise of your question is flawed in several areas.  1) It assumes from the outset that accepting cash is tantamount to fraud. 2) Your example has nothing to do with accepting cash, but instead global accounting practices, which while maybe distasteful, are in fact legal, 3) Your **personal** belief that unethical equates to criminal is only **your** belief 4) The actual question ("how to ..") is so broad to be effectively unanswerable (and as per @ajd) the answer you opposed is arbitrary.

Comment: @PeterM. Thanks for your comment. Regarding 1) and 3): fair enough. I added the disclaimer to avoid the "unethical is less serious than criminal" (local laws are simply the local formalization of the local ethical point of view).
Regarding 2) unfortunately when travelling I can pay either by cash or by credit card. I am stuck in this dicotomy. Regarding 4), I updated the title to limit the reach of my question to what it actually is, i.e. fiscal matters. "How to" are common questions, I am not looking for opinated answers but for a rational objective way to solve this issue. Thanks

Comment: This seems more like a rant than a question.

Comment: If you compare the charges debit and credit cards charge with the model of something like WeChat you might conclude that you are contributing to (legal) criminal behavior by using a card.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany if you could not check charges/fees, it would be criminal. If you can have a look at them, it is up to you to accept them. Here I am not questioning the (old) business model :) .

Comment: @EarlGrey Usually the fees are baked into the price you pay, since the merchant has to eat them.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany now I see your point. I added a clarficiation. Not everyone is aware that creditcards are free for the client, but the business on the receiving end has usually fixed fees + some % on the total amount fees

Comment: @EarlGrey Credits Cards are not necessarily free for the client, as if you are traveling the CC company will add on whatever fee they deem reasonable for performing a currency conversion between where you made the purchase and where the CC is based.

Comment: @PeterM the credit cards I use have fees, but they are traceable and explained. For example: currency conversion is performed with a markup of 0.25%, minimum 0.50cents of €/$/£, at the rate declared by "currency conversion provider" on the time of the transaction registration, which can be an arbitrary number of day after when I paid. Complex? yes. Explained? yes. It may be that I picked credit cards that are particulary clear in their contracts, I do not know.

Comment: of all the crimes and unethical behaviours one might encounter or be part of while travelling, surely tax evasion by a credit card processor must be a VERY long way down the list. More importantly there's no travel aspect to this question. The worry, and OP's proposed solution, apply identically when buying groceries around the corner from your home.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to travel, but to spending in general, anywhere

Comment: @KateGregory "around the corner from your home" 
At home I can use the EC card from my cooperative bank, which I can exactly control what are doing with the money earned from the fees. As for your statement on corporate tax evasion (not all countries are a tax haven as Canada), please do not extrapolate from your personal (canadian) situation to anyone in the world.

Comment: @EarlGrey I am ignoring all your digs about Canada to simply say that even if I knew for sure every single business I interacted with on a trip was 100% evading all their taxes, I would still have bigger things to worry about like are they paying their staff fairly, are they polluting, are they exploiting their vendors as eg Walmart does, can I trust them not to skim my cc details and reuse them later, and literally dozens more "corporate misbehaviours" before I got to tax evasion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of expenses.

On restaurants and hotels just ask for a receipt (and tell you need for tax reasons). Usually they provide you something real, and because both of you use the same reason "less taxes", they cannot really argue. Also tell in advance if you can pay with card (and maybe explaining that you want to keep some cash for minor transactions). In this case, if they refuse ("terminal is not working", just change restaurant: this is a major incentive: the lost income is very probably larger than the taxes they would "save").

For minor purchases, the two methods become inconvenient, so use your gut feeling (and maybe ask for receipt). but in such case, also the "stolen money" is minor. But I tend not to like such countries, and world is big enough to choose a new country to like (or dislike). OTOH lack of trust on government (and corruption) is not a problem tourist could solve (but we can help the honest people).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I do not agree 100% on "the "stolen money" is minor", beacuse both corporate taxes and VAT are proportional to the amount, so apart from rounding errors, the stolen money cumulative amount is similar.
The main issue I have is that I have a definite lack of trust on **my** government, especially regarding corporate accountability, so it is a resident problem which (in principle) I could solve :) !

Comment: @EarlGrey: I mean: for my minor purchases. Obviously it add (with all other customers),  but many tourists are not so ethical, so I do not think I can do a difference (but with hotel, restaurants, and "large" expenses)..

Answer (score -10):

To minimize the global reward of VAT/tax elusion, I proceed this way.

I assume foul play in both cases (local business and credit card provider).

- if VAT in the country I visit is higher than the corporate tax in my country, where my credit card provider is fiscally based, I pay with the credit card (VAT paid, corporate tax on credit card not, tax money will sooner or later enter into the economy of a country not having anything to do with visited or home conutry)
- if VAT in the country I visit is lower than the corporate tax in my country, where my credit card provider is fiscally based, I pay cash ((VAT not paid, corporate tax on credit card not, additionally money spent in the visited country stay there in cash and sooner or later will enter the official economy)

Comment: This seems very arbitrary and I'm not sure how it's useful to other travelers

Comment: @ajd thanks for your input. Do you have a better approach?

Comment: Do not travel to countries where many sellers are not paying their taxes. That is a much surer way not to give money to people who do not pay what they are due. (But also look at the sellers in your own country, they might be dishonest as well.)